# Sweet alert disable touch outside in android

Tags: android

Im having a trouble how to disable when clicking outside sweet alert , When I click outside the sweetdialog the sweet dialog gone I already tried 
dialog.setCancelable(false); dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false); and setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);
but it seems it conflicts, please try this out below is my current code , thanks in advance

[image]

> MainActivity.java

```
public void alert_dialog(){
    new SweetAlertDialog(MainActivity.this,SweetAlertDialog.SUCCESS_TYPE)
            .setTitleText("Good jobss!")
            .setContentText("You clicked the button!")
            .show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just refer the SweetAlertDialog by a variable and then set it to cancelable.
like this
**Java**

```
SweetAlertDialog sDialog = new SweetAlertDialog(this, SweetAlertDialog.SUCCESS_TYPE)
sDialog.setCancelable(false);
sDialog.show;
```

**Kotlin**

```
val dialog = SweetAlertDialog(this, SweetAlertDialog.SUCCESS_TYPE)
            dialog.setCancelable(false)
            dialog.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

> I just realized I shoud make an variable declared final

```
   final SweetAlertDialog pDialog = new SweetAlertDialog(
                    MainActivity.this, SweetAlertDialog.SUCCESS_TYPE);
            pDialog.setTitleText("Good jobss");
            pDialog.setContentText("You clicked the button!")
            pDialog.show();
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
```